# Is this an effective way to prevent a web scraper from finding my email on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, email, web-scraping

Imagine a webscraper, scraping websites looking for emails and contact information. Below I have included how I present my email to visitors, please give me your thoughts on why or why not this would work?

```
   <button id="reqBtn" type = "button" class = "btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="showEmail()">
      Request
  </button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function showEmail(){
         var array = ['t@','m.com'];

          document.getElementById('reqBtn').innerHTML = 'suppor'+array[0]+'mydomai'+array[1];
      }

  </script>
```

This presents a button on my webpage, after the 'Request' button is clicked, it will display the email. My logic behind this is that since I am storing the '.com' and '@' part of the email in an array, that the HTML scraper would not be able to put the pieces together to find the email along with the user action of pressing the button first. Is this effective?

Comment: Belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<button id="reqBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="showEmail()">Request</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function showEmail(){
    var email = window.atob('dEBtLmNvbQ==');
    document.getElementById('reqBtn').innerHTML=email;
  }
</script>
```

You can use the `window.atob()` method.

According to MDN:

> The WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.atob() function decodes a string of data which has been encoded using base-64 encoding. You can use the btoa() method to encode and transmit data which may otherwise cause communication problems, then transmit it and use the atob() method to decode the data again.

So if your email is t@m.com, you can encode it firsthand using `.btoa()` and then grab the output:

```
window.btoa('t@m.com')
// result: "dEBtLmNvbQ=="`
```

and in your code you can use the `.atob()` method:

```
<button id="reqBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="showEmail()">
  Request
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function showEmail(){
    var email = window.atob('dEBtLmNvbQ==');

    document.getElementById('reqBtn').innerHTML=email;
  }

  </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

> I think using an inquiry form is much easier. You have to use HTML code though. Below is the standard code for a Inquiry box on a site. For more information, I recommend looking into [link](http://www.tourcms.com/support/webdesign/enquiry_form.php). It has more detail into the process. There are many ways to hide your email, do not assume that javascripting with arrays!!! is the only way to do so.

```
<form id="contact_form" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-
data">
<div class="row">
<label for="name">Your name:</label><br />
<input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value=""    
size="30" /><br />
</div>
<div class="row">
<label for="email">Your email:</label><br />
<input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" 
size="30" /><br />
</div>
<div class="row">
<label for="message">Your message:</label><br />
<textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="30">     
</textarea><br />
</div>
<input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send email" />
</form>
```